# using xpaths in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, xpath, cross-browser

I have a large set of XPaths for selecting content in webpages and I want users to be able to use them in the browser (including IE).

What do you recommend? 
Try and interpret the XPaths with JavaScript?
Or perhaps convert to regex?

Some existing JavaScript XPath work:
http://js-xpath.sourceforge.net/xpath-example.html
http://goog-ajaxslt.sourceforge.net

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question doesn't it?

Comment: What makes you think XPath could be converted to regex?

Comment: About using regex to parsse HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: PLEASE STOP LINKING THAT ANSWER IT MAKES ME ANGRIER THAN THE GUY WHO WROTE IT /<html>.*<\/html>/g KAJSHDKAJSHDKASHD

Comment: @MooGoo: I haven't tested them though. Was hoping for feedback from anyone with experience here.

Comment: Agreed, that post is linked too much. http://blog.sitescraper.net/2010/06/web-scraping-with-regular-expressions.html

Comment: @Richard: What browsers are you targeting? I ask because up today `selectNodes` works for IE and `evaluate` works for Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari...

Comment: interesting - am just targeting IE and FireFox

Comment: @Tomalak: the full picture is I have been asked to manually convert the xpaths to regex but I want to come up with an automated alternative

Comment: @Richard: That does not answer my question.

Comment: @Richard: You can even parse an XPath expression with RegExp...

Comment: @Tomalak: your question was why do I think I can convert XPath's to regex. Because I can. Atleast for the XPath's I need to deal with. But as I said I don't want to spend my time doing that. Got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look for an XSLT javascript library. Since most modern browsers have built-in XSLT support, and XSLT includes support for XPath, it is possible to use that engine to power your XPath selectors.

Personally, I've used Sarissa and the Glyphix jQuery.xslTransform libraries successfully:

- http://jquery.glyphix.com/
- http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/

This looks interesting too:

- http://johannburkard.de/software/xsltjs/

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays browsers support the XPath 1.0 based  [DOM 3 XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) out of the box. The main API is the `document.evaluate` function which [is available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate) in all mayor desktop browsers except IE.

And there are polyfills, if you want to use it in older browser versions or IE.