# Parsing HTML by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, domparser

I need some help in JS. Basically I want to write a function in JavaScript which takes XPath of the webpage and returns the `innerHTML` of that Xpath. Something like this

```
function : getXpath(my_xpath)
{
  // JS Code that will parse the above Xpath and returns an InnerHTML as value
   return value.
}
```

In the above example, the xpath = `"/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]"`

So how should I get an `innerHTML` that is present in last `div[2]`.
I want to use pure JavaScript.

PS For people who wants to suggest some JS Libraries or frameworks.
PLEASE EXCUSE!!!

Comment: i think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695146/using-xpaths-in-javascript

Comment: sorry but i placed my comment before this edit 'PS For people who wants to suggest some JS Libraries or frameworks. PLEASE EXCUSE!!!"

Comment: Have you looked at the MDN for this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript